# PHP set a function var from false to true from outside the class

Tags: php, class

There is an annoying function inside a class which adds advertisements and I want them removed from outside the class. The function looks like this:

```
class Ads_Form {
    public function admin_footer( $submit = true, $show_sidebar = true ) {
        if ( $show_sidebar ) {
            $this->admin_sidebar();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a variable called `$show_sidebar` which is set to `true` by default.

How can I set this var to `false` from outside the class?

Comment: You can't.  Why not set it to `false` there or when you call it?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I understand where you coming from - it's the most logic way. But I'm making a plugin so others can also benefit from this, so it must be called from outside the class.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Is there perhaps a way to remove this class?

Comment: This is way too unclear as to exactly what you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'd be glad to explain it - I'm using WordPress, and WordPress plugins must use hooks to archieve something, there's no straight editing the file you want to have edited. So I must archieve how to edit this plugin without editing the file directly.

Comment: When you use it do you have to use `new Ads_Form` or could you use `new MY_Ads_Form`??? Or you are not actually using this class, something else is calling it?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Someone else is calling it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method, if you provide no arguments, it will default to false:

```
$obj = new Ads_Form();
$obj->admin_footer();
// $show_sidebar gets set to true
```

Just pass it arguments, which will override the defaults:

```
$obj = new Ads_Form();
$obj->admin_footer(true, false);
// $show_sidebar gets set to false
```

Comment: Tried this but my screen goes blank. Do you know what causes this?

Comment: "Do you know what causes this?" Spelling false wrong? :)

Comment: False is spelled right. ;) I'm using WordPress so it's kinda figuring out how to get this working from a plugin pov.

Comment: If you're getting a crash and the only change you're making is adding two parameters to this method call, then your problem isn't WordPress's plugin system. Check your error logs.

Answer (score -1):

**Difficult to achieve without editing the file itself. Either way you are going to have to edit the class, or every file / function that calls this function.**

Rather than remove the class or change the defaults, if you have permission to edit the class file, just comment out the line:

```
// $this->admin_sidebar();
```

This will prevent any calls to this function from being overwritten, and it will disable the ads elsewhere.

You can also just change the default value:

```
admin_footer( $submit = true, $show_sidebar = false )
```

Comment: That indeed works but it needs to be called from outside the class.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Ads_Form {
    public $show_sidebar = true;

    public function admin_footer($submit = true, $show_sidebar = null) {
        if(!is_null($show_sidebar)) {
            $this->show_sidebar = (boolean)$show_sidebar;
        }
    }

    if($this->show_sidebar) {
        echo 'test<br>';
    }
}
```

Test code!

```
$Ads_Form = new Ads_Form;
echo '------------TEST 1-------------<br>';
$Ads_Form->admin_footer();
$Ads_Form->show_sidebar = false;
echo '------------TEST 2-------------<br>';
$Ads_Form->admin_footer();
```