# Replace class variable from outside the class

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class

I want to replace *(if that's not possible: remove)* a class variable from outside the class.

The class is like this:

```
class Frontend {
    protected function __construct() {
         add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'debug_marker' ), 2 );
    }

    public function debug_marker() {
        $marker = sprintf(
            '<!-- This is some advertisement HTML to advertise our product -->',
        );

        return $marker;
    }
}
```

How can I replace `$marker`? *If that's not possible, how can I remove it in any way?*

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726877/php-set-a-function-var-from-false-to-true-from-outside-the-class

Comment: In this and previous questions, you appear to be trying to use an existing class or plugin for WordPress that you can't modify and want to keep it from displaying ads.  The way you are asking to do this is not possible.  Show your code and how you use the class and ask how to keep the ads from displaying, NOT how to remove a variable from a class.

Comment: @RiggsFolly There's no way for me to change anything within the class. Everything must be done outside the class. Is that possible to archieve?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for that link, was about to repeat what others had already done on other question

Comment: @J.Doe No but you may be able to extend the class but you haven't given near enough code or info to tell. BTW, with the given code that variable does nothing.

Comment: Should that code read `$this->marker = sprintf(.....)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Please see the question again, it's updated.

Comment: The `debug_marker()` method still does not do anything

Comment: This is my last comment:  IF YOU CAN'T CHANGE `Frontend` HOW ARE YOU USING `Frontend`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly In the construct it adds it to the source code.

Comment: Yes, but the method sets a variable `$marker` which is in LOCAL SCOPE ONLY and therefore the method actually achieves NOTHING... outputs NOTHING, changes NOTHING

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry I missed the return statement, please see the question again.

Comment: Would it be a big job to subclass this original class and change all the references to `Frontend` to `myFrontend` for example

Comment: @RiggsFolly that would be a big job, it's a class with 1940 lines

Comment: Then I give up too.Anyway I just realised this is Wordpress and dont know much about that from a coding perspective

Comment: I added the WordPress tag, maybe you will get come useful help now

Comment: Well I have a soft heart and just thought about you @J.Doe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843586/best-way-to-remove-a-specific-html-comment-from-source-code-using-php

Answer (score 0):

The variable is inaccessible as long as it is private and inside the class, to use it would have to be public and still create the object, or you can create a method to be able to modify it.

```
<?php

class Frontend {
    private $marker = '';

    public function debug_marker() {
        $marker = "<!-- This is some advertisement HTML to advertise our product -->";
    }
    Public function SetMarker($var){
        $this->marker = $var;
    }
    Public function GetMarker(){
        return $this->marker;
    }
}


$front = new Frontend();
$front->SetMarker("Hello");
echo $front->GetMarker();
```

So you can modify your variable with this metod when you want, but only if you have the instance of the class

Comment: Thank you for your input but that is sadly not going to work for me as I cannot edit the class whatsoever. It all needs to be done outside the class (because it's a third party plugin, when they update their plugin my custom code would be gone).

Comment: please read my edit, i test it, so is working :), but if is a plugin forget it, if you cant modify the code you can't acces to the var.